# newtonsoft JSON serializer unable to deserialize collection with c# property initializer

Tags: json.net, deserialization, c#-6.0

Say you had a simple object as follows:

```
    public class PaymentLineItem
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public PayCodeDto PayCode { get; set; } //= PayCodeDto.Invalid;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return StringUtils.ToString(this);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as PaymentLineItem);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = TimeStamp.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Amount.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Description != null ? Description.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (PayCode != null ? PayCode.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(PaymentLineItem other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        return TimeStamp.Equals(other.TimeStamp)
               && Amount.Equals(other.Amount)
               && string.Equals(Description, other.Description)
               && Object.Equals(PayCode, other.PayCode);
    }
}
```

There is nothing special with this class apart from usage of the new C# auto-property initialize introduced in C# 6.0.  *PayCodeDto* is simple with three properties and implements IEquatable.

If you create a collection of these payment items and serialize this using

```
   var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sut);
```

and you then take the correctly serialized string and deserialize using

```
  var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PaymentLineItemLight>>(serialized);
```

what you end up with is a collection all instances of the line items having  the same PayCode.

This is the sample test:

```
 [Test]
        public void Should_Serialize_Collection_In_Package_Correctly()
        {
            var sut = new List<PaymentLineItemLight>
            {
                new PaymentLineItemLight
                {
                    Amount = new decimal(153.0000),
                    Description = "48385 - Multiple items payment",
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-30T10:40:47.477"),
                    PayCode = new PayCodeDto("105", "dont-care") {DictionaryId = 2}
                },
                new PaymentLineItemLight
                {
                    Amount = new decimal(53.0000),
                    Description = "483816 - Multiple items payment",
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-30T10:40:47.477"),
                    PayCode = new PayCodeDto("104", "dont-care") {DictionaryId = 2}
                },
                new PaymentLineItemLight
                {
                    Amount = new decimal(200.0000),
                    Description = "483817 - Multiple items payment",
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2018-01-30T10:40:47.477"),
                    PayCode = new PayCodeDto("102", "dont-care-102") {DictionaryId = 2}
                }
            };

            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sut);
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PaymentLineItemLight>>(serialized);

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(sut, deserialized);
        }
```

If I remove the auto-property initialize, the test passes.  I must be missing something here.  Anyone seen this?

Comment: Collection initializers is a way to construct objects. You can't add it to or remove it from a type. What do you mean by "remove the auto-property initialize"?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve], but I *think* the problem may be that Json.NET will **populate** a pre-allocated reference property.  Since `PaymentLineItem.PayCode` are all initialized to point to the same global instance `PayCodeDto.Invalid`, that is what gets populated.  Try marking the property with [`[JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ObjectCreationHandling.htm).

Comment: Also, you don't show `PayCodeDto`, but IMHO if you are going to share global instances you should make it be immutable.